# Node child_process.exec Displays Special Characters as Question Marks

Tags: node.js, encoding, electron, exec, child-process

I'm running a test using Node's child_process.exec to execute an echo  statement with special characters in it.

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
try
{
    exec("echo téstér",
        function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log(stdout)
        });
} catch(e){
        console.log(e.message)
}
```

When running this on my Linux machine, I get the **téstér** value I was expecting.  When I run it on my Windows machine I get back **t?st?r**.

Am I missing something when I callthe exec function to have my special characters appear?

Comment: Might be related:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7940.

Have you tried piping the output to a file?

Comment: @fardjad I don't believe that's the issue.  I'm able to run that example code with the é character and have it return back what I expected.

Comment: It's probably cmd.exe. Does it work in PowerShell? What's your Windows version?